# How to check if WordPress is updating plugins?

Tags: plugins, updates, api

I have a simple dependency check at the start of some plugins - which check if another plugin is installed and active (using `class_exists()`).

This works well in the normal WordPress flow - as the plugin that includes the required class is set to instantiate earlier and I also re-order the available plugins so this plugin is loaded first - like this:

```
    /**
     * Force this plugin to load first
     * 
     * @since   0.1
     * @return  void
     */
    public function load_this_plugin_first() 
    {

        // grab plugin directory + file name ##
        $path = plugin_basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/'.basename(__FILE__);

        // grab the list of active plugins ##
        if ( $plugins = get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) {

            // check if out plugin is in there ##
            if ( $key = array_search( $path, $plugins ) ) {

                // push it to the top of the list ##
                array_splice( $plugins, $key, 1 );
                array_unshift( $plugins, $path );
                update_option( 'active_plugins', $plugins );

            }

        }

    }
```

This all works well until I need to update a plugin - then the other plugins are all deactivated - as all the `class_exists()` checks return false.

So, I'd like to know if there is a *constant* - such as DOING_AUTOSAVE for plugin updates - something like DOING_PLUGIN_UPDATE?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of re-ordering your plugins to load in a specific order, have each of them that requires some other plugin to be loaded to defer their initialization until the "plugins_loaded" action hook.

In other words, when a plugin with a dependency is included and ran, it shouldn't do anything directly. Instead, it should have functions, and then add_action calls to hook those functions to plugins_loaded. That function that is called later can do the class_exists check and act accordingly.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I'm going to need to re-write a few things then I'll come back with feedback!

Comment: little juggling - changed a few methods to static and got this all working nicely - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

How about using WP_INSTALLING? - this check is placed above the main plugin Class...

```
if ( ! class_exists( 'REQUIRED_CLASS_NAME' ) && ! defined( 'WP_INSTALLING' ) )  { 

    // give some notice to the user ##
    add_action('admin_notices', function(){
        $plugin = get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );
        echo "<div id='message' class='error'><p><code>".$plugin["Name"]."</code> has been deactivated because it requires the <a href='#'>PLUGIN NAME</a>.</p></div>";
        if ( isset( $_GET['activate'] ) ) {
            unset( $_GET['activate'] ); // remove the activation notice ##
        }
    });

   // turn this plugin off ##
   add_action('admin_notices', function(){
      deactivate_plugins( plugin_basename( __FILE__ ) );
   });

   // stop this plugin from running ##
   return;
}
```

Then the actual plugin class is below:

```
if ( ! class_eixsts( "Plugin_Class" ) ) 
{ 
    Plugin_Class() 
    { 
      ... 
    } 
}
```